# How to get edits of a particular question from the Stack Exchange data dump

Tags: support, edits, questions, data-dump

I want to see all the edits that were made to a Stack Exchange question. In other words, how a question has changed over time, maybe by editing tags, removing grammatical errors, or something else.

How can I find this using the Stack Exchange data dump or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) might help; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1474350/edits-of-a-particular-post?PostId=11227809&opt.textResults=true) is a query which returns the initial version of and the changes to the famous question [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4751173)
It does return the Markdown of the body, not what's rendered. Also, SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Alternatively, you could use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) which gives realtime results. [Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=11227809&filter=!nKzQUQx*Kx&site=stackoverflow&run=true) is a list of revisions for that same question.